# Python setter not executed when setting nested property

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have the following Python code to represent the velocity of an object.

```
class Vector(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y

class Physics(object):
  def __init__(self, velocity):
    self.velocity = velocity

  @property
  def velocity(self):
    return self._velocity

  @velocity.setter
  def velocity(self, velocity):
    self._velocity = velocity
    self._hi_res_velocity = Vector(velocity.x * 1000, velocity.y * 1000)
```

My intent is for `velocity.x` to set both `_velocity.x` and `_hi_res_velocity.x`, but the setter isn't run in this case. I get the following:

```
>>> myObject = Physics(Vector(10, 20))
>>> myObject.velocity.x = 30
>>> myObject._velocity.x, myObject._hi_res_velocity.x
(30, 10000)
```

I think the getter for `velocity` is run and then `x` is set on that returned value, but is it possible to implement the behavior I want using properties? I feel like I'll have to rewrite my logic to make this work.

Comment: `velocity.setter` only works when assign a new value to `velocity`, not `velocity.x`

Comment: You can use `myObject.velocity = Vector(30, 20)` instead or make _hi_res_velocity a property with a customized get()

Comment: Right, so I'm assuming there's no trick to run a method in `Physics` when a property of `Vector` is modified and I should come up with a different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
myObject.velocity.x = 30

|_______________|
        |
        |___ this part already resolved the property
```

The `myObject.velocity` is already returning a `Velocity` instance, and this happens first.  Then the `.x` which follows is just a normal attribute access, since the `Vector` class doesn't define a descriptor for handling `x`.

I'll suggest a different design, make either the "velocity" or the "hi_res_velocity" a getter-only, i.e. one of them is computed from the other whenever needed.  This will resolve your issue, and also has the advantage that you don't have to store the same state twice.

Comment: Having it getter-only sounds like the cleanest solution, only 1 copy of the data and it avoids this issue